# Android : Want to display notification dialog like facebook

Tags: android

I want to display a dialog when click on action item in action bar like facebook type. But i am not getting how to show white arrow (Selected item at the bottom of selected action item) when dialog appears. does it is image replacement when click on action item ? Please help.

Comment: Screenshot will help users to understand more

Comment: I can not submit image due to less reputation on stack overflow

Answer (score 3):

```
 public class WebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        ProgressDialog pd; // Create Proggress Dialog to show if User Internet connection is slow


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
            if (!loadingFinished) {
               redirect = true;
            }
        loadingFinished = false;
        view.loadUrl(urlNewString);
        return true;
        }





        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            loadingFinished = false;
            try
            {
                if(pd == null){
                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "",Constants.REQUEST_LOADING_STRING, true);
                    pd.setCancelable(false);
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(!redirect){
               loadingFinished = true;
            }

            if(loadingFinished && !redirect){
              //HIDE LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
                try
                {
                if (pd.isShowing()) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            } else{
               redirect = false; 
            }

         }

    }
```

Comment: You haven't read my question properly.

Comment: can you explain your question more ...... while i just think you want to show a dialog box or progress bar dialog in your webview when page loading is strated if not give me some sample code or example which express your questions clearly

Comment: Hi Ahmad, I want to show notification popup window as like facebook android app. When we click on action item in android facebook app it displays a popup dialog.

Comment: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu   this is a sliding pop up menu example may it help you https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CreateNotificationActivity :

```
public class CreateNotificationActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void createNotification(View view) {
        // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
        // notification is selected
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        // Build notification

        NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fm)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setContentIntent(pIntent); //Required on Gingerbread and below

        noti.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti.build());
getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // hide the notification after its selected





    }
}
```

NotificationReceiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reciever);
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't read my question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by making a own dialog class which is extended from PopUpWindow. and display this dialog just below the action item in action bar. So it will look same as Facebook dialog when any one click on action bar's item.